# Connect External SQLite database in Android Studio,Need some guidance

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my Database Design. I have 2 Tables "**Donation_Details**" & "**Information**".Let me clarify it,Now I can't call this two table out, What's the problem with these? I'm stuck at here almost 1 day... I'm trying to find answer myself But No answer at all...
[image]

**This is my DatabaseOpenHelper**

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "eBossCharity.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

**This is my DatabaseAccess**

```
public class DatabaseAccess {
    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;
    Cursor c = null;

    private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
        this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void open() {
        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        if (db != null) {
            this.db.close();
        }
    }

    public String getAddress(String name){
        c=db.rawQuery("Select * from Information ",new String[]{});
        StringBuffer buffer =new StringBuffer();
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            String address = c.getString(0);
            String address1 = c.getString(1);
            buffer.append(" "+ address +" "+ address1);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

**And this is my Java page**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                databaseAccess.open();

                try {
                    String n = summary_showAll.getText().toString();
                    String address = databaseAccess.getAddress(n);

                    summary_showAll.setText(address);
                    databaseAccess.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```

Do I wrongly type something to cause this bugs?

Comment: Do you test to see if `c` is non-`null` before you start trying to call methods on that object?

Comment: @T3rrance Low: When you say `crash`, you should also say `stack trace`. Posting the crash log from [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) will really help find the issue quickly.

Comment: how to test it? @Shawn

Comment: testing a Cursor returned from `rawQuery` (or any SQLiteDatabase method that returns a query ) for null, is useless. Such methods will return a valid Cursor, if there are no rows in the Cursor then the count (e.g. `c.getCount()`) will return 0.

Comment: Run a query using the following SQL `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'`(within the App) this will list all the tables (if you loop through the cursor and output the name column to the log). Perhaps you have inadvertently not saved the database since creating the table (assuming that you're using an SQL tool to create the database). Also edit your question to include the stack_trace.

Comment: I've Update my Question. Hope you guys can understand my problem and sorry about that I'm not good in expression.

Comment: You've completely changed the question. Before you were saying that you could access the **Information** table but not the **Donation_Details**  and you said the App was crashing for the latter. That's all gone now and you are now just stuck, which means very little. You need to clarify exactly what issue you are having and if the issue is that the App is crashing you need to include the stack-trace, otherwise all that people can do is guess as to what the issue is.

Comment: Noted. Thank you very much. @MikeT

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. All you need to do is **uninstall** and **reinstall** your app. It worked for me.

 Hope this help.

Comment: After uninstall and reinstall. It becomes worse...QAQ

Comment: I've updated my question. Please refer back. I don't know what I have typed to cause me can't connect with my database @Toan Tran